# How to turn X, Y integer coordinates into the correct pixel coordinates in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a dataset that contains X and Y coordinates as integers. There are many different files and the X,Y coordinates differ from being close to each other to being negative and far from each other. The coordinates are supposed to show where a node in a network is supposed to be, but I am having problems representing this in GUI using javafx. 
Some (most) of the files contain X,Y coordinates that are to small and so they cluster at the center of the screen, but if I scale them by multiplication then other files which have other X,Y values will appear outside the window.

[How most of the files look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GuO5.png)

Comment: Have you thought about zooming in and out that would allow you a closer look at areas with dense points?

Comment: scale(by multiplication or use the builtin zoom functionality - maybe better as you can zoom in and out) and use a scrollpane(little tricky with zooming but possible) or use panning.

Comment: Without knowlege about the distribution of those coordinates, it's hard to suggest a good way of computing good display coordinates for the vertices. Maybe applying the logarithm to the radius of a polar coordinate system helps, but this would requires the possibility to identify a center...

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid pane, or make sure you have a resizable constraint, that is not anchor pane